# calling a long running vb6 com object in classic asp .. time out error

Tags: com, asp-classic, vb6

I have a long running vb6 Com object called from a classic asp page

it works perfectly when there is not a lot to do but it times out if it has to do a lot.

is there a way of calling it async so it wont time out or

could i call a progress bar to keep on refreshing the client so it wouldnt time out ?

```
Set objQReport = Server.CreateObject("ReportGenerator")

mainRpt = objQReport.GenerateReport(MySessionRef) ' times out here sometimes

Set objQReport = nothing
```

any tips would be helpful

Comment: Can you just increase the ASP timeout with Server.ScriptTimeout=x (seconds)?

Answer (score 2):

Web technology is not really suited for long-running tasks, but you have several options:

One option is to do an AJAX-call to a second ASP page. As soon as you're ASP is running, the server will finish the process, even if the client (the browser/AJAX that did the actual call) is no longer connected.

This method ***does*** use web-technology to process a long running task and the downside is that you are burdening your IIS machine with performing this long-running-task, leaving less performance for the thing IIS is good at; serving webpages.

So in your landing page (say default.asp) do an AJAX call to your (long-running) report page. How to do an ajax call depends on what (if any) javascript library you use. in Jquery it would be something like this:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    /* AJAX call to start the report generation */
     $(document).ready(function(){
            $.get("[URL_OF_YOUR_LONG_RUNNING_PROCESS]", function(data) 
                {
                    alert(data);
                });
     });
    </script>
```

As you can see I am alerting any data that is returned from this URL, but in your case that is probably not what you want. You want your visitor to keep browsing while the long running process keeps working.

This way, the URL is called asynchronously. The server will start processing the URL and the browser doesn't have to wait for it. The server will continue and finish the long running task in the background.

Please note that **you will still have to increase the server.scripttimeout** on your asp page that runs the long process. This just makes sure that the user can continue browsing, the server will still respect the server.scripttimeout setting that is configured, and fail if it takes too long.

A widely used second option is to use a message queue. A message queue accepts messages and guarantees delivery of these messages, even if the computer or network goes down.

Microsoft Windows has MSMQ built in (you'll have to enable it in the software settings), and you can use this from classic ASP. The queue will store messages and deliver them to a *consumer*. The consumer is something you need to write yourself; an application that can read a queue and process the messages inside.

What you do is have ASP write a message to the MSMQ, containing information on what task to perform and its parameters.
Your consumer application will have to poll the MSMQ, read the message and start the long-running process. This will then run completely independent of IIS, and can even be run on a totally different computer (MSMQ can run across networks).

The downside of this second method is that you will have to write a consumer, most likely in a bit more low level language like VB or C# (though you might be able to use Python for example), and preferably write it as a service. I don't know how comfortable you are in (one of) these languages, but if you wrote the COM object yourself, it would be trivial to write an executable in VB6 that polls an MSMQ and calls the COM object.
Below are some links to get you started.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/173339

http://technosock.blogspot.nl/2007/07/microsoft-message-queue-from-classical.html

http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=131272&seqNum=6

Hope this helps,

Erik

Comment: It shouldn't be a problem to use MSMQ Triggers to have the background worker fired up by MSMQ when work arrives in the Q.  This worker can probably even be a WSH script if need be.  There isn't any need for a continuously polling process to be kept running, and for that matter Q events work better than polling anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the addition, Bob77. I wasn't aware of that. I've only used MSMQ with a polling service.

Comment: Hi thanks for the tips How do i use the MSMQ object when calling my object ? see my code above

Comment: @roughanbass, check out the first link in my post, it's an ASP example from microsoft.

Comment: Hi there the customer wont let me write a consumer application that runs on the server listening for messages .. ill have to do it the Ajax call ... have you any examples on how Ajax can call a com object async.i would really appriciate it

Comment: @roughanbass, I have expanded on the AJAX method in my answer. It's just a client-side call that the browser does to start another ASP page a-synchronously.